Setting multiple language environments in LaTeX
Suppose I want a LaTeX document with two languages, that is Thai and English, with different fonts for each language. Let's say I want a font named 'TH Sarabun Chula' for Thai while 'Latin Modern Roman' (the default font) remains for the English. Normally, what I would do is add fontspec and polyglossia package, then set Thai as the main language and add English as the additional language under \Efont; as follows:
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TH Sarabun Chula}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt  

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\Efont{Latin Modern Roman}

This 'TH Sarabun Chula' font is smaller compared to Latin Modern Roman so I made a command \lm based on \Efont to make the English one smaller, thus removing the difference in size between fonts.
\newcommand{\lm}[1]{
    {\small{\Efont{#1}}}}

Most of my documents uses Thai as the main language; so whenever I wanted to use the English environment, I would use the \lm command and I got what I desired. Here are some parts of the code for my lecture notes that use this command.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item งาน \lm{(work)} คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างเป็นระเบียบ
    \item ความร้อน \lm{(heat)} คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างไม่เป็นระเบียบ
\end{itemize}

สมมติว่าเราให้ความร้อนโดยต้มน้ำในหม้อจนเดือด จะสังเกตได้ว่าจะเกิดการสั่น เคลื่อนที่ไม่เป็นระเบียบ 
นั่นแสดงว่าความร้อนได้กระตุ้นให้โมเลกุลของไอน้ำสั่นและเคลื่อนตัวไปมาอย่างไม่เป็นระเบียบ 
เราอาจการเคลื่อนที่ดังกล่าวว่าเป็นการเคลื่อนที่ความร้อน \lm{(thermal motion)}

I could keep going with this method, but it is so tiring of writing this \lm{...} everytime. I wonder if there's any other way that I can transition between two (or multiple) language environments without setting commands like the above. (just typing them in the body and it will automatically change the typeface right away.)
I appreciate any help in advance. Thank you.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippets be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I don't use polyglossia, but is that really changing the language or only the font?  Or does polyglossia detect the change? fontspec allows you to scale a font to match another when you set it up. This would be more automatic and more satisfactory than using \small. Is there a TeX font people can reproduce your code with?

You can do this with Babel (or with Polyglossia, as @cfr has already posted).  One advantage to using Babel with LuaLaTeX is that it can automatically detect the language you are typing in and change fonts accordingly, with no need for any tags or environments.
This MWE also scales all fonts to the same x-height, but you can adjust the font size by adding a Scale= option in front of each font that needs it.  I also loaded unicode-math, but fontspec and other math packages would work as well.
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Make it an error for letters to be missing.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{thai}

% TH Sarabun Chula is available from https://www.arts.chula.ac.th/ling/tag/ipa/

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{NewCM10-Regular}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}
          {TH Sarabun Chula}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item งาน (work) คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างเป็นระเบียบ
    \item ความร้อน (heat) คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างไม่เป็นระเบียบ
\end{itemize}

สมมติว่าเราให้ความร้อนโดยต้มน้ำในหม้อจนเดือด จะสังเกตได้ว่าจะเกิดการสั่น เคลื่อนที่ไม่เป็นระเบียบ 
นั่นแสดงว่าความร้อนได้กระตุ้นให้โมเลกุลของไอน้ำสั่นและเคลื่อนตัวไปมาอย่างไม่เป็นระเบียบ 
เราอาจการเคลื่อนที่ดังกล่าวว่าเป็นการเคลื่อนที่ความร้อน (thermal motion)

This line is in English.
\end{document}



In future, please always provide compilable code rather than snippets. This makes it easier for people to help and more likely the answers will be applicable to your real document.
You can scale the font for English, which is preferable to relying on \small since it will scale properly at different sizes. (\small doesn't take an argument, by the way.)
However, you still need to tell LaTeX to switch languages. This is not just a matter of changing fonts. As far as I know, polyglossia can't detect this automatically, so you need to temporarily activate the alternative language. You can make \lm a shortcut for \textenglish{} which is a macro provided by polyglossia for switching, but that does not, of course, mean less typing.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Thai}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt  

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{thai}
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\NewCommandCopy \lm \textenglish
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item งาน \lm{(work)} คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างเป็นระเบียบ
  \item ความร้อน \lm{(heat)} คือการถ่ายโอนพลังงานที่ทำให้โมเลกุลเคลื่อนตัวอย่างไม่เป็นระเบียบ
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

To cut down on the typing, create a key-combination in your editor of choice, so you don't have to manually write \lm{} each time. Better yet, have it insert \textenglish{} or whatever so your code is more transparent and your markup semantic rather than appearance-based.
No image supplied due to Okular-on-X bug, but the output looks awful with Noto Sans Thai and LM anyway. (Missing Thai characters and horribly mismatched weights.) So the code is for purely illustrative rather than decorative.
